# Returning file for download REST (Java)

Tags: java, rest

I have my REST response set up like so:

```
@MethodMapping(value = "/download", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public Response getLogFile() {
    File log = new File("path");
    if (log.exists())
    {
        return Response.ok(log, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + log.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
                .build();
    }
}
```

But the link just gives me a text response rather than a download:

```
{"status":200,"entity":{"path":"path"},"metadata":{"Content-Type":["application/octet-stream"],"Content-Disposition":["attachment; filename\u003d\"proteus.log\""]},"entityClosed":false,"entityBufferred":false}
```

The two packages I'm using are javax.ws.rs.core.Response and javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.

Am I understanding the functionality wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please paste the response headers? Also, what library/framework are you using?

Comment: Added to the main post!

Comment: Have you tried creating a stream from the file and passing it to the constructor of the response?

Comment: Are you using Wickets? You may be mixing features from Wicket (`@MethodMapping`) and from JAX-RS (`Response`).

Comment: @wastl I haven't and I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @approxiblue I am using Wicket, is that what's causing the problem? I'm pretty new at this. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, your method is inside a class extending `AbstractRestResource<JsonWebSerialDeserial>` right? Returned objects will be serialized as JSON. If you want file downloads, you need to [mount another resource](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicketstuff-restannotations-parent#mounting-resources-to-a-specific-path), probably a `ByteArrayResource`.

Comment: Or if you want to stay in the same class, you could try setting up a `MultiFormatSerialDeserial`. I'm not sure.